# Delphi using DLL Pointer Parameter

Tags: delphi, pointers, dll

I am working with a DLL from RFIdeas and the documentation indicates the usage for the DLL function is:

```c
short GetActiveID32(BYTE *pBuf, short wBufMaxSz)
```

They don't have Delphi examples, but do have VB.NET, C#, and others. Here is the excerpt for C#:

```cs
public static void getActiveID()
{
    pcproxlib.SetDevTypeSrch(PRXDEVTYP_USB);
    int rc = pcproxlib.usbConnect();
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    if (rc == 1)
    {
        IntPtr result1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(32 * sizeof(int));
        byte[] arr = new byte[32];
        int nBits = pcproxlib.GetActiveID32(result1, 32);
        if(nBits == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNo Id Found, Please put card on the reader and make sure it must be configured with the card placed on it");
            return;
        }
        int Bytes = (nBits + 7) / 8;
        if (Bytes < 8)
        {
            Bytes = 8;
        }
        Marshal.Copy(result1, arr, 0, 32);
        String cardData = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < Bytes; i++)
        {
            String data = String.Format("{0:X2} ", arr[i]);
            cardData = data + cardData;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + nBits+"Bits" + ": " + cardData);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Reader Not Connected");
    }
}
```

I have the following function defined in Delphi.

```pascal
function GetActiveID32( CardID : pInt; Max_Buffer_Size : integer ) : word; stdcall external 'pcProxAPI32.dll';
```

I call the function like so:

```pascal
// Connect to USB Reader
SetConnectProduct( PRODUCT_PCPROX );
SetDevTypeSrch( PRXDEVTYP_USB );
USBDisconnect;

try
  DeviceID := 0;
  Results := GetDevCnt;
  Results := USBConnect( );
  if Results <> 0 then
  begin
    // Get Active USB reader ID
    //CardID := 0;
    repeat
      Sleep( 250 );
      Results := GetActiveID32( @CardID , 32 );
      BytesToProcess := ( Results + 7) / 8;
      if ( BytesToProcess < 8 ) then
        BytesToProcess := 8;

//    StrLCopy( BytesArray, PInt( CardID ), 32 );
//    Marshal.Copy(result1, arr, 0, 32);

      CardData := '';

      for I := 0 to Trunc( BytesToProcess ) do
      begin
        CardData := CardData + BytesArray[ i ];
      end;
    until Results > 0;

    // Disconnect from USB Reader until next needed
    USBDisconnect;
  end;
except
  on E : Exception do
  begin
    results := GetLastLibErr;
    ShowMessage( 'Error reading card ' + Results.ToString);
  end;
end;

lblCardValue.Caption := String( @CardID );
```

The caption is always garbage. What am I doing wrong? I think it has something to do with my misuse of pointers.

Comment: Even the C# is wrong. `short` in C is 16 bits (at least on Windows), but C# `int` is 32 bits.  The C# code allocates an array of 32 ints, i.e. 128 bytes, but says to the function that it is a byte array of length 32. I'm sure that there are many other mistakes in the C# code.  The Delphi code, well, who knows. You didn't give enough information. For instance, we don't know what CardID is. You make the mistake of using floating point arithmetic rather than integer arithmetic. You ask the function to populate CardID, whose contents you then ignore.

Comment: It would be nice to have some more info on what the actual result should be (did you try the C# code?). But regarding the dll routine itself, i think you need to specify ‘max_buffer_size’ as a short instead of integer. Second, maybe the routine uses another calling convention like cdecl instead of stdcall...

Comment: @R.Hoek You don't think the fact that the code ignores the data returned by the native function is a problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well that surely is also a big problem as it’s commented out in the example. It would be nice if Larry would edit the code so it represents the exact code that should work. As I’m also missing the memory allocation (aka Delphi type) for the CardID, which he provides as buffer.

Comment: @R.Hoek Thanks everyone for helping out. Here is the what is expected:ID: 33 Bits
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 3E A1 0B 18, this data is from their utility used to test the reader/credential, and so we know the correct data.  I did not try the C# code, I assumed it was correct and am trying to convert that into Delphi. I will change max_buffer_size to short and test. I will try cdecl.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. Thanks for the help. The code commented StrLCopy is my attempt to convert the C# code Marshal.Copy. I commented out because I don't think I'm using the StrLCopy correctly and wanted to research more the Marshal.Copy method. It seems there are several overloads, still researching. So I thought I was using CardID in the lblCardValue.Caption, is that a missuse?

Comment: I was looking at the code above. You seem to have put in lots of code that we are expected to ignore. And yet you've also left out lots of useful stuff. We would work out the calling convention if the pinvoke declaration was here. And we can't see important variable declarations. My advice is that you spend time refining your code so that you can ask a concise yet complete question. These questions are easy enough to resolve but the information has to be clear.

Comment: As David said. First : Please make the code ‘complete’: you did not write all c# code in Delphi code and did not show al variable declarations. Second: give a try with Visual Studio to see whether the c# sample code actually works. If not, the sample code probably wont work in Delphi eigther.

Comment: I've made some changes and am close. The issue now is when running in debug mode the program stops at this code: `CardData := CardID^.ToString;`When I hover the mouse pointer over CardID^ the data is correct, $3EA10B18. However the error message is: 'access violation at 0x00600e5e; read of address 0x3ea10b18'. It seems like the program is trying to access the data at memory location 0x3ea10b18 instead of using it as data. Once the code is working I will post here.

Comment: @Larry that’s you are asking by doing CardData^. And since you did not allocate memory (as far as I can tell from the sample code you supplied) it’s a wonder the routine returns data at all. But still we need more info on the routine to help you any further... Read the comments David and I left earlier and modify the questions sample code to regarding the missing parts...

Comment: Ok, so I've made changes and would like to edit my original question/code. Can I do that? I think I have cleaner code for review.

Answer (score 0):

We finally have a resolution. Below is the code that works. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

```
     //function USBConnect( DeviceID : integer ) : SmallInt; external 'pcProxAPI32.dll';
    function USBConnect( DeviceID : integer ) : word; stdcall external 'pcProxAPI32.dll';

    // short GetActiveID32(BYTE *pBuf, short wBufMaxSz)
    function GetActiveID32( CardID : PByte; Max_Buffer_Size : word ) : word; stdcall external 'pcProxAPI32.dll';

    // BSHRT USBDisconnect(void)
    function USBDisconnect : word; stdcall external 'pcProxAPI32.dll';

var
  frmMain  : TfrmMain;
  DeviceID : integer;
  Results  : integer;
  CardInfo   : ^Byte;

const
 PRODUCT_PCPROX  : integer = 1;
 PRXDEVTYP_USB   : integer = 0;

procedure TfrmMain.btnReadCardClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CardData       : string;

begin
  ShowMessage( 'Place card on reader' );

  // Connect to USB Reader
  SetConnectProduct( PRODUCT_PCPROX );
  SetDevTypeSrch( PRXDEVTYP_USB );
  USBDisconnect;

  try
    DeviceID := 0;
    Results := GetDevCnt;   //Only one device should be on system

    Results := USBConnect( DeviceID ); //Connect to the only device on system

    if Results <> 0 then
    begin
      repeat
        Sleep( 250 ); //Requried 250ms delay between reads
        Results := GetActiveID32( @CardInfo, 8 );
      until Results > 0;

      USBDisconnect;  // Disconnect from USB Reader until needed next

      CardData := IntToHex( Integer( Pointer( CardInfo ) ), 8 );

    end
    else
      ShowMessage( 'Unable to connect to reader' );

   except
   on E : Exception do
   begin
     results := GetLastLibErr;
     ShowMessage( 'Error reading card ' + Results.ToString);
   end;
  end;

  lblCardValue.Caption := CardData;  // Display data from card

end;
```

This is the code that actually resolved the issue.

```
CardData := IntToHex( Integer( Pointer( CardInfo ) ), 8 );
```